# Use derived class instance as default parameter value

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, forward-declaration, default-parameters

I need a static method of my `Base` class to have a default parameter value of type `Derived`.
Is there a way to implement this without use of overloading? (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2653212/1116364)).

```
class Base;
class Derived;
Derived make_derived(void);

class Base
{
  public:
    static void problem_here(Base && = make_derived());
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

Derived make_derived()
{
  return Derived();
}
```

... gives me an error about the usage of the incomplete type `Derived`. How ever, I cannot place the definition of `Derived` in front of `problem_here` because it must be defined after the definition of its base class `Base`.

Unfortunately, returning a pointer from `make_derived` is not an option.

Overloading `problem_here` is the only thing I came up with until now, but as the "real" `problem_here` method takes 2 (and another one 3) parameters, and it's part of a library, this gives me ...

```
static void problem_here(Thing const &, Base const &);
static void problem_here(Thing const &, Base &&);
static void problem_here(Thing const &); // Default param "hack"
static void problem_here(Thing &&, Base const &);
static void problem_here(Thing &&, Base &&);
static void problem_here(Thing &&); // Default param "hack"
```

.. for only the two parameter case.

Is there a way to avoid writing all those function signatures, while still maintaining the same performance (no unneccessary copy/move construction for any parameter constellation) and same behaviour on the caller site?

---

I should add that there are multiple functions like `problem_here` and all need access to the protected constructor of `Derived` (and to those of its many siblings). So the main reason to make these methods static members of Base is to be able to `friend class Base;` in each of the derived classes instead of friending every function.

---

Refactoring showed me, that I could move the code accessing the protected constructors of the derived classes into a single factory function. That way, I'm able to move the functions with the default parameters outside `Base` and let the call the factory. Now I still have to friend every one of those functions, but only a single time (in `Base` to give them access to the factory). I could circumvent this by placing all functions into a helper class and friending it instead, but that looks like a hack to me.

```
class Base
{
  friend class Helper; // The Hack
  friend void no_problem_here(Base &&); // No hack, more writting


  protected:
    static void factory(Thing && from_which_I_can_construct_the_correct_derived_class);
    // return type void to keep it simple, move parameter type because special cases
    // handled in "trampoline" functions and a copy of the Thing must be stored either
    // way.
};
class Derived : public Base
{
  friend class Base;
  // protected constructor omited for simplicity.
}


void no_problem_here(Base && = make_derived());
// ...
void no_problem_here(Base && b)
{
   // work, and then call Base::factory
}

// or

class Helper
{
  protected:
    // Constructors ...
  public:
    static void no_problem_either(Base && = make_derived());
};
```

Comment: What does `problem_here` do? Can't you just move it outside `Base`?

Comment: In the real case, it uses its first parameter to determine which (there are more than just `Derived`) derived class to instantiate, combines this with the second parameter and returns that. For that it needs access to the (all protected because of strong preconditions) constructors of the derived classes. As there are multiple functions like this, I would need to friend each of them in every derived class.

Comment: I suppose [a template base](https://ideone.com/4ZsPat) is out of the question.

Comment: At first I thought yes, but letting the template base inherit from the realy base could partially work... (Like `Derived` -> `Interim<Derived>` -> `Base`) ... but would take the method out of the scope of `Base`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make declarations multiple times, so the following workaround might help:

```
class Base;
class Derived;
Derived make_derived(void);

class Base
{
public:
    static void problem_here(Base &&);
};

class Derived : public Base {};

void Base::problem_here(Base && = make_derived()) { /* ... */ }
```

If there's a problem factoring the code like that, you can always insert a little trampoline function:

```
 class Base
 {
 public:
     static void problem_here(Base &&);
 private:
     static void problem_here_impl(Base &&);
 };

 inline void Base::problem_here(Base && x = make_derived())
 { problem_here_impl(std::move(x)); }
```

Comment: Isn't it easier then to introduce the overloaded function declaration `inline void Base::problem_here() { problem_here(make_derived()); }` ?

Comment: @DanielOertwig: That would have different semantics, as it wouldn't allow `problem_here(my_other_derived())`.

Comment: Of course, if I use overloading: `static void problem_here(Base &&);` and `static void problem_here(void);`. But refactoring really showed me something: I was able to move all the code that needs access to the derived constructors into a single factory function, which doesn't take default parameters but can be called from the (now trampoline-like) functions with default parameters (which I have moved outside the base class, see edit of my question). So using trampline(s) and moving the default parameter functions outside `Base` actually solved this.